# Time complexity of recursive Longest Common Subsequence which uses a map

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subsequence, clrs

I was reading 'Algorithms Unlocked' by Thomas H Corman and came across an approach to finding the Longest Common Subsequence which ran in O(n * m). This approach can be seen in this article too: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-longest-common-subsequence/

This seems to be the most popular and quickest approach but seemed a bit convoluted to me so I tried to write a different approach, also using dynamic programming.

*My approach is recursive, in the worst case has to branch twice every call but uses memoization to save the result of previous inputs. I understand that std::map can take lg(n) time for 'find' but I assume this code can be easily altered to use a hash map instead*

```
using namespace std;

string lcs_helper(int i, int j, const string& x, const string& y, map<pair<int, int>, string>& memoizedSolutions)
{
    if (memoizedSolutions.count({ i, j })) return memoizedSolutions[{i, j}]; 

    if (i == 0 || j == 0) return "";

    if (x[i] == y[j])
    {
        string lcs = lcs_helper(i - 1, j - 1, x, y, memoizedSolutions);
        lcs.push_back(x[i]);
        memoizedSolutions[{i, j}] = lcs;

        return lcs;
    }

    string lcs1 = lcs_helper(i - 1, j, x, y, memoizedSolutions);
    string lcs2 = lcs_helper(i, j - 1, x, y, memoizedSolutions);

    if (lcs1.size() >= lcs2.size()) // corrected bug
    {
        memoizedSolutions[{i, j}] = lcs1;
        return lcs1;
    }

    memoizedSolutions[{i, j}] = lcs2;
    return lcs2;
}

string lcs(string x, string y)
{
    map<pair<int, int>, string> memoizedSolutions;

    return lcs_helper(x.size() - 1, y.size() - 1, x, y, memoizedSolutions); 
}
```

I am struggling to generalise the time complexity of my approach and wanted to know if and why it is slower than the usual approach.

*I tried to understand the time complxity through creating a tree with an example but am still struggling to generalise it.*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wg3p.jpg (This was the tree example I created, red= return "" and the other colours represent inputs that can be memoized, I have ommited the trees for memoized results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use a hashmap for memoization, and correct the bug, the time complexity is `O(m*n*l)`, where `l` is the length of the LCS; this is also upper-bounded by `O(m*n*min(m, n))`.

First, the bug. `lcs_helper` returns a string:

```cpp
string lcs1 = lcs_helper(i - 1, j, x, y, memoizedSolutions);
string lcs2 = lcs_helper(i, j - 1, x, y, memoizedSolutions);

if (lcs1 >= lcs2)
```

This `if` statement should compare the lengths of the strings; it actually compares them lexicographically.

---

To find the time-complexity of a dynamic-programming algorithm, a handy formula is `(number of subproblems) * (time to solve one subproblem)`.
Here, you have the same number of subproblems as the regular DP solution: `m*n`, or one for each value of `i` and `j`.

The time to solve a subproblem, in your case, is not `O(1)`. Since your function returns a string, and must cache strings for memoization, it will do up to `length(LCS)` work per subproblem to build the string and copy the memory.

This may be why the normal DP algorithm can look convoluted: if you store the actual LCS strings, the run-time will become cubic in the worst-case. By only memoizing on the lengths of the LCS, and having `lcs_helper` return a length, you'll need to backtrack at the end to construct the string, but maintain an `O(m*n)` runtime.

Comment: 'The time to solve a subproblem, in your case, is not O(1). Since your function returns a string, and must cache strings for memoization, it will do up to length(LCS) work per subproblem to build the string and copy the memory.' 
Could I get some more clarification for this, why does returning the string take length(LCS)? 
Furthermore, assuming inserting into the hashmap is constant, what if I used a string reference instead and at each subproblem built up my LCS. Would this achieve O(m * n)?

Comment: @60q If inserting into the map is constant, and you returned a reference, then yes, it would be `O(m*n)` (also, assuming you use unordered_map instead of map). Maybe I'm not enough of a C++ expert, but I don't see how you could do constant-time inserts that easily. Who would own the string that your hashmap values point to?

Comment: @60q If there is some kind of return value optimization happening, returning the LCS could possibly take less than the length of that string. I was assuming that different calls of  the lcs_helper function would have to copy the string, since it's being both cached and modified.

Comment: The string would be created in the lcs function as opposed to lcs_helper and its reference would be passed to lcs_helper as an argument. lcs_helper would then append to this string reference, eliminating the need for returns. However, I think I understand your point ,in that to cache the string, a copy of the string must be made and the time taken for this copy would increase with the size of the string; and not be constant like I assumed.